# How to display tooltip value in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tooltip

In WPF, I created a rectangle like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"                    
                    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner"
                    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner.Controls"
                    x:Class="GeoOvwSample.RectangleGeometryRoundedCornerExample"
                >

<Brush x:Key="ItemStroke">#FFD69436</Brush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ItemBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        <GradientStop Color="#FAFBE9" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<Brush x:Key="ItemStroke1">#ACADCD</Brush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ItemBrush1" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
    <GradientStop Color="#FEFEFE" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#BDBEDE" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<Style x:Key="FlowChartRectangleStyle" TargetType="Rectangle">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource ItemBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource ItemStroke}"/>
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="StrokeLineJoin" Value="Round"/>
    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill"/>
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>    
</Style>

    <Style x:Key="Data" TargetType="Rectangle" BasedOn="{StaticResource FlowChartRectangleStyle}">             
</Style>

<Style x:Key="Data_DragThumb" TargetType="Rectangle" BasedOn="{StaticResource Data}">
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="300"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>        
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="DataShape" />   
</Style>


<s:Toolbox x:Key="FlowChartStencils" ItemSize="100,90" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ItemsControl.Items>

   <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource Data}" ToolTip="DataTest" StrokeThickness="2">                                
    <s:DesignerItem.DragThumbTemplate>                    
        <ControlTemplate>                        
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource Data_DragThumb}" x:Name="DataShape" Tag="DataShapeTag" />
         </ControlTemplate>
     </s:DesignerItem.DragThumbTemplate>                
    </Rectangle>

    </ItemsControl.Items>

    </s:Toolbox>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This displays a rectangle on the panel, and I can select and drag it in my GUI. Now I want to create a kind of textblock on the shape so that it displays its tooltip value, and thus the tooltip value appears together with the shape all together. I tried to create the textblock and bind it with the rectangle shape but somehow my code is not correct. How to do it? Or is there a simpler method? Thank you.

Comment: Go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502964/how-to-programatically-show-a-wpf-c-windows-control-tooltip

Comment: I am looking for a way to do it in the xaml but not in the code behind. Any suggestion?

Comment: Silverlight offers a class called "ToolTipService" which can be used to display tooltips for Silverlight controls. This class can be attached to most of the UI elements in Silverlight to display tooltips.

Comment: Please go through this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36930/Tooltip-service-and-tooltip-facility-of-WPF.it should be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the `TextBlock` into any container control with (but *after*) the `Rectangle` element and then data bind the value of the `Rectangle.ToolTip` to the `TextBlock.Text` property. Try something like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Rectangle Name="Rectangle" Style="{StaticResource Data}" ToolTip="DataTest" 
        StrokeThickness="2" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ToolTip, ElementName=Rectangle}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I tried as you said, added "<TextBlock Text="{Binding ToolTip, ElementName=DataShape}" />" right after "</Rectangle>" but it didn't work.

Comment: Could that be because you are using "StackPanel"? Because mine is "s:ToolBox" and "Rectangle" comes inside "ItemsControl.Items".

Comment: It *could* be any reason... I can't see your code, so can't comment.

Comment: I updated my question with full code. Could you help?

Comment: Just use the code that I provided you with in place of your `Rectangle`. To be honest though, your code is such a mess... anything could be going wrong. We just don't write XAML like that in WPF. We don't generally define items inside an `ItemsControl.Items` property like that. And does your code even compile? It shouldn't... you should have an error that says *The type 'Rectangle' does not support direct content.*

Comment: Sorry, but you've got too much wrong for me to help further. You need to learn WPF *before* you come here to ask questions... there's no point in wasting my time answering your questions if you won't understand the answers. I can't be your personal tutor.